# Watch syntax help

Tags: command-line, programming

In my Systems Programming class, there are weekly programming experiments, and I'm having trouble with the current one.

The objective is to write a C program that slowly writes a string of text to a file, metered by `usleep()` in a 100 count for loop.

The goal of the experiment is to observe the file size buffer in action via the watch command.  However, I can't get it to work using `watch -d ./output`

What syntax do I need for the watch command to see the changes made to the file size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `du` to check a file's size (strictly speaking, its disk usage):

```
watch -n 1 du output_file
```

If you want shorter than one second intervals, you can also execute `du` in an endless loop, sleeping afterwards for, say, 0.1 seconds:

```
while true; do du output_file; sleep 0.1; done
```

Or remove the sleep entirely.

Have a look at `man du` for more options.